# How to create a sub folder called “dimens” in Android Studio under Values folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, directory, dimensions, subdirectory

I want to create a sub folder called `dimens` under `values` folder. 
But I can't create it...

However it exists sample about it. For example see the following picture

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply: you don't. That "folder" is created when you create multiple files (with different configuration) of the `dimens.xml` file.

If you for example try to create 2 different `dimens.xml` one for a ratio and the other for a different one, that folder will automatically appear :D